# How to use single function libraries functions to execute multiple applications in QTP?

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I'm using Keyword Driven Framework for Web Applications where in my application three applications are integrated and we are using same keywords for three applications,now i want to execute those 3 applications with same keyword instead of maintaining 3 function libraries for 3 applications because now page titles are same for 3 applications and i want to execute the applications based on program types.

Function Library one:

```
Function openBrowserUrl()
Application one Function
End Function
```

Function Library Two:

```
Function openBrowserUrl()
Application Two Function
End Function
```

Function Library Three:

```
Function openBrowserUrl()
Application Three Function
End Function
```

Now i want to combine as a single Unique function then it should work as

```
If App_one="Y" then 
Application one - use same unique function
Different Credentials
End If

If App_Two="Y" then 
Application Two - use same unique function
Different Credentials
End If

If App_Three="Y" then 
Application Three - use same unique function
Different Credentials
End If
```

Please provide solution how to achieve this one

Comment: What does execute multiple applications mean?

Comment: 3 programs are integrated into one application,each program having different logins but same modules and same functionalities.

Comment: are the login pages and object properties different for all the 3 integrated applications ?

Comment: No, Object properties are same.

Answer (score 0):

Well then it's pretty straightforward... No need to use any if else statements, just make use of the parameters.

Function Library one:

```
Function openBrowserUrl()
 StrUserId = "ID1"
 StrPwd = "pwd1" 

 f_Login(StrUserId, StrPwd)
End Function
```

Function Library Two:

```
Function openBrowserUrl()
 StrUserId = "ID2"
 StrPwd = "pwd2" 

 f_Login(StrUserId, StrPwd)

End Function
```

Function Library Three:

```
Function openBrowserUrl() 
  StrUserId = "ID3"
 StrPwd = "pwd3" 

 f_Login(StrUserId, StrPwd)

End Function
```

Login function

```
f_Login(StrUserId, StrPwd)
' Enter the code for login here.
End function
```

Moreover, you can combine openBrowserUrl function to one.

```
Function openBrowserUrl(strURL, strUserId, strPwd)

'open browser and login here

End function
```

Comment: K,when coming to login function,will i need to write each login function in each function library or how it'll?

Comment: As you said that login page object properties are same for all the 3 applications, you just need to pass parameters(separate credentials) to one single login function. No need to have 3 login functions now.

Comment: k,but i'm facing problem while calling one function of one function library into another function library.

Comment: The logic is to be defined in such a way that all the calls to login functions are referring to one single function. All the libraries need to be attached to QTP/UFT so that this login function can be called from anywhere in the test or other libraries

Comment: It is saying function is not exist.

Comment: i did same still same issue in uft 12.02

Comment: Ok, I need 2 things, 1) the login 
 function code, 2) the code that makes a call to login function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150260/discussion-between-rajesh-om-and-mithilesh-indurkar).